# Mongoose Promise not passing data to next chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I am querying MongoDB using mongoose with promise. The result is accessible only in the first `.then(function(results){ // can send the result from here..})`. But when I manipulate the results and pass it to the next `.then()`chain it is not accessible. Below is the full function.

```
exports.getAcl = function(req, res) {

  User.findAsync({}, {
    acl: 1
  })
  .then(function(results){
    var aclList = [];
    results.forEach(function(result,index,arr){
      aclList[result._id] = result;
      if (index === (arr.length - 1)) {
        console.log('I can log the aclList here..', aclList)
        return aclList // But neither able to send it to next chain nor to front end res.send(aclList) 
      }
    })
  })
  .then(function(aclList){
    console.log(aclList) // Loging undefined
    res.status(200).json(aclList); // undefined
  })
  .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here..thanks

Comment: Where is `findAsync` coming from?  It's not in Mongoose.

Comment: @kyrylkov I am using bluebird with mongoose. `var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));`

Comment: @Jasnan: Newer versions of mongoose also support promises out of the box

Comment: @Jasnan Mongoose 4 `find` returns a `Query` which has `then` method http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
results.forEach(function(result,index,arr){
  aclList[result._id] = result;
  if (index === (arr.length - 1)) {
    console.log('I can log the aclList here..', aclList)
    return aclList // But neither able to send it to next chain nor to front end res.send(aclList) 
  }
})
```

try

```
var resArray = [];
results.forEach(function(result,index){
  aclList[result._id] = result;
  if (index === (arr.length - 1)) {
    newRes.push(aclList);
  }
})
// console.log(resArray) to verify they are there
return resArray;
```

Bottom line: don't use multiple returns per function (as in `forEach`).

Comment: hi..it still didn't work. thanks for the bottom line tip. I replaced the `forEach` method with `.map` and now it worked.